# Where is do_execve located?

Tags: kernel, exec

In Linux, there is a function called `do_execve` in `fs/exec.c`.

Where is the object file of the function located after Linux has been compiled? Where is the `.ko` file that contains it?

Answer (score 4):

As you mention, the function is defined [in `fs/exec.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.3/source/fs/exec.c#L1878) (see also [the corresponding identifier search](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/do_execve) on the Elixir Cross Referencer).

That file isn’t built as a kernel module, so it’s not in a `.ko` file; it’s part of the main kernel file. To see that, look at [the `Makefile` in the same directory](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.3/source/fs/Makefile); `exec.o` is listed in `obj-y`, so it’s built-in.